# A couple of questions about programming in Xcode 4.2, Bugs or just bad programming?

Tags: xcode

im totally new at stack overflow, I usually just research stuff myself but I just started using xcode 4.2 and I cant help finding it weird.

These are the issues:

why cant i multiply by (1/2) but i can by 0.5? If i try the first option it will think its 0.

and second, is this if statement wrong?

```
if (-1 < x < 0)
```

I could swear i have done that in other programming languages but it wont work here, so i had to change to if `((-1 < x) && (x < 0))`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: My guess would be that 1/2 think that you want an int result and therefore the 0.5 "real result" is being rounded down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Xcode, it's to do with the C language.

The first issue:

```
x * (1 / 2)
```

The C compiler treats `1` and `2` as ints, and in integer math, 1 / 2 = 0. If you want to multiply as floats, you can do:

```
x * (1.0 / 2.0)
```

or

```
x * ((float) 1 / (float) 2)
```

In your second issue, the compiler will interpret `(-1 < x < 0)` as `((-1 < x) < 0)`, which is obviously not what you want, since `(-1 < x)` will return either 0 for false, or 1 for true. To do compound logic statements in C, you need to use `&&` for AND or `||` for OR:

```
((-1 < x) && (x < 0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed Im a bit rusty haha but you made it quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

Bugs?  Bad programming, all the way.

Integer division has bitten you.  Make it 1.0/2.0 and you'll get the 0.5 you expect.

That code `if (-1 < x < 0)` isn't correct.

Comment: FWIW, `-1 < x < 0` is valid in Python (and means what you would expect).

Comment: I guess I don't know Python well enough, then.

Comment: It's a feature that is probably used less often than it ought to be. Here's the relevant bit from the docs: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Greg.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `1/2`, that is performed in integer arithmetic, and so is equal to `0`.  Try multiplying by `1.0/2.0`.

And yes, that if statement is wrong (assuming that you want to check whether `x` falls within the range -1 to 0).

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not syntactically correct so it has nothing to do with Xcode.

1/2 is integer division, which would evaluate to the truncated integer. So floor(1/2) = 0 and the behavior is indeed correct.

Same with the if statement. if (-1 < x < 0) just isn't syntactically correct.